# Beamer Overlay Replacing items

Tags: beamer, overlays, presentations, block

I have an itemize list with three elements which I would like to uncover after each other.
Every item comes with two "examples", represented by blocks. I would like to uncover the three items one by one, but only show the example blocks directly after its item and make them disappear when the next main item comes.

The code looks like this:

```
\begin{frame}
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item<1-> Topic 1
    \onslide<2>{
        \begin{block}{Example}
        \enquote{Example 1}
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Example}
        \enquote{Example 2}
        \end{block}
    }
   \item<3-> Topic 2
    \onslide<4>{
        \begin{block}{Example}
        \enquote{Example 3}
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Example}
        \enquote{Example 4}
        \end{block}
    }
   \item<5-> Topic 3
    \onslide<6>{
        \begin{block}{Example}
        \enquote{Example 5}
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{Example}
        \enquote{Example 6}
        \end{block}
    }
   \end{enumerate}
    
  \end{frame}
```

So, the slides would look like this:

1. only 1, without examples
2. only 1, with examples
3. 1 and 2
4. 1, 2 and examples of 2
5. 1, 2 and 3
6. 1, 2, 3 and examples o 3

Is there a way to do this?